# Overloading: method with more params calling method with less params

Tags: overloading

I'm having an argument with my colleague. When overloading two methods, is it considered bad practice for the one with more parameters to call the one with fewer parameters?

For example:

```
method (P p1, P p2, P p3) {
       <do something with p1 and p2 => newP>;
       method (newP, p3);
}
method (P p1, P p2) {
       ....
}
```

Comment: What is the argument for why this is a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload chaining like this is a common practice (in particular with constructors) - I wouldn't call it bad, though it can be abused like most language features.

As far as it reduces code duplication, it is a good practice. Most of the time, I find it is also more readable.

I would say that using this technique is a matter of personal opinion and style rather than absolute good or bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general paradigm used in constructor calls, i.e the one with more parameters calls the method with lesser parameters and then continues its initialization with the remaining parameters. I don't think its a bad practice in the context of construction of objects, but I'm not sure if it makes sense in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this practice we can go for method with multiple parameters in some case  like printf in c. Java also supports now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good practice because it hides details.Although the example you show seems to go the other way around.

I would expect the one with lesser paramaters to call the one with more + defaults.
You are calling the one with less detail from the one with more detail. Somehow that smells fishy but perhaps it is just because i am not familiar with this approach,